# php edit/add new getting mixed up using POST/GET from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For help with creating a website backend, I was following this tutorial -> http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/ But my edit button does not work correctly; instead, when a user clicks on it at an existing row, gets redirected to an update form and inputs the values, a new row gets added to the table instead of editing the existing row.

I have the edit/add php code in the same file like so:

```
<?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

//connect to database
include ("newDBconn.php");

//creates the new/edit record form, with a function that makes it easily reusable since this form is used multiple times

function renderForm($first= '', $last='', $error = '', $groomingid = '')
{ ?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="adminnewstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>
<h1><?php if ($groomingid != '') { echo "Edit Appointment"; } 
else
{
    echo "New Record"; }?> 
</h1>    
</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php if ($groomingid != '') { echo "Edit Appointment"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?> </h1>    

        <?php if ($error !='') {
            echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
                            ."</div>";
        } ?>

       <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <?php if ($groomingid != '') { ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="GroomingID" value="<?php echo $groomingid; ?>" />
                        <p>ID: <?php echo $GroomingID; ?> </p>
                      <?php } ?>

                      <strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text"
 name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" /> 
                    <br />
                    <strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/>
                   <p>*required</p>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </div>
       </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php }

/*
Edit Record

*/
//if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record 
if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']))
{
    //if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            //make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
            if (is_numeric($_POST['GroomingID']))
                {
                    //get variables from the URL/form
                    $groomingid = $_POST['GroomingID'];
                    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES);

                //check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
                    if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
                        {
                //if they are empty, show an error message and display the form

                        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                        renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error, $groomingid);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE grooming SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ? WHERE GroomingID=?"))
            {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $groomingid);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
            }
            //show an error message if the query encounters an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare sql statement.";
            }

            //redirect the user once the form is updated
            header("Location: PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    //if the 'id' variable isn't valid, show error message
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
    //if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else
    {
        //make sure the 'id' value is valid
        if (is_numeric($_GET['GroomingID']) && $_GET['GroomingID'] > 0)
        {
            //get 'id' from URL
            $id = $_GET['GroomingID'];

            //get the record from the database
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM grooming WHERE GroomingID=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $groomingid);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->bind_result($groomingid, $firstname, $lastname);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                //show the form
                renderForm($firstname, $lastname, NULL, $groomingid);

                $stmt->close();
            }

            //show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }
        }
//if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the PS_Manage_Appnts.php page

        else 
            {
                header("location:PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
                exit();
             }
        }
}

    /* NEW RECORD

    */
    //if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
    else
        {
            //if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                //get the form data
                $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES);

                //check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
                if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
                {
                    //if they are empty, show an error message and display the form

                    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                    renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error);
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert the new record into the database
                    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT grooming (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                    {
                        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                    }
                    //show an error if the query has an error
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error: could not prepare sql statement.";
                    }

                    //redirect the user
                    header ("location:PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
                    exit();

                }

            }
            //if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
            else
            {
                renderForm();
            }           
}
//close the connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I'm wondering if the mix up has to do with the code being in the same page or if I'm just mixing up where to use $_Get and $Post (or something else entirely). I've checked and re-checked and re-checked with the code in the tutorial, browsed stackoverflow for similar answers and hints, but I've come up empty so far. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are checking for parameter `GroomingID` coming in via GET – but it isn’t, of course, because it is in a hidden field in a form with method POST.

Comment: @CBroe Are you suggesting that I remove the 'hidden' attribute from that particular input or...?

Comment: No, whether an input field is of type `hidden` or any other type does not change the `method` the form uses to send the data …

Comment: @CBroe so are you saying that if I change the `method` to 'get' instead of 'post', that will fix my problem?

Comment: No, it will not, because in the rest of your code you are expecting the parameters to be send via POST again … what will fix your problem is _proper debugging_, to see what parameters your script actually receives, and into which if/else-branches it goes.

Comment: thank you for your help and sorry about the stupid questions; I'm clearly still inexperienced enough to not know when debugging is necessary. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']))
{
    //if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
```

As your form posts to the same page - without adding a query variable `GroomingID` - the first condition evaluates to false when you POST an edited form.

You should check for POST or GET:

```
if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']) || isset($_POST['GroomingID']))
```

or:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['GroomingID']))    // assuming there are no cookies with the same name
```

Comment: okay I've changed `if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']))` to `if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']) || isset($_POST['GroomingID']))` and I'm still having the same issue.